# No prominent links to the ServerFault blog?

Tags: discussion, blog, hyperlinks

Trying to find the ServerFault blog, I had to go through:

- one of the "blog" links at the top/bottom of the page, http://blog.stackexchange.com/
- from the sidebar there, http://blogoverflow.com/
- and finally a link to http://blog.serverfault.com/

Is that too many steps? Should it be linked from the About page or even the main link set, replacing the current "blog" link?

Answer (score 4):

The current blog link at the top of the page is *normally* a link to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) (please, don't get us started).
This particular usurping of the chat link's rightful place was triggered by the StackExchange API posting, but the ServerFault blog also frequently steals that spot.

We also already have a (permanent) link to the blog in the site footer:
[image]
I'll agree this isn't very prominent ([footers get no respect](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCVR_ajL_Eo)), and I think it may get bounced around when there's a new post on the StackOverflow blog, but when there's something new the SF blog will evict Chat from the top of the page, and since you'd have to be down in the footer to find the "About" link normally I doubt adding the blog to the about page would really do much.

Comment: Ah, it's on the main page footer but not the meta footer (that's going to blog.SE).

Comment: The blog links all over the SE network are F^%$#d up.  On Serverfault, the blog link in the footer takes you to the SF blog, on other sites the footer link takes you to the site-wide blog.  I've never noticed that the footer link on Meta.SF takes you to the site-wide before.  And, of course, the changing link on the top of the page is giving everyone except John Gardeniers indigestion.

Comment: @Ward There is actually some method to this particular madness: Sites that *have* a blog (SF, SU, Gaming) have their footer link to the site's blog.  Sites that don't (AskUbuntu, Math) get sent to blog.stackexchange.com.  (well OK, it's either method or pure coincidence).  I have **no** idea why Meta doesn't link to the appropriate site-specific blog though.